# Setting a cell color in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set a cell color in excel by a VBA function.

If I call the following code in a cell by setting =test(0) then it sets the cell green, as expected.

```vb
Sub change_cell_color(c1 As Range, colorval As Long)
    c1.Interior.ColorIndex = colorval
End Sub
```

```vb
Function Test(x As Long)

    With Application.Caller
        .Parent.Evaluate "change_cell_color(" & .Address(False, False) & ", 10)"
        
    End With

End Function
```

However, if I try to parameterize the function so that I can set an arbitrary color, then the function fails.

```vb
Function Test(x As Long)

    With Application.Caller
        .Parent.Evaluate "change_cell_color(" & .Address(False, False) & ", x)"
        
    End With

End Function
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: As a rule of thumb (ok, more than that): Never modify something using a UDF. It's simply not the idea of a UDF.

Answer (score 2):

Your `x` is denoted as text inside your quotation marks.

Try:

```
Function Test(x As Long)

    With Application.Caller
        .Parent.Evaluate "change_cell_color(" & .Address(False, False) & ", " & x & ")"
        
    End With

End Function
```